# What is a proper way to implement a state engine with asynchronous events?

Tags: python, django, workflow, celery

I am developing a travel itinerary booking engine. The use case is like this:

1. customers make a reservation for a journey that involves multiple legs (a leg is a contiguous  part of the journey, operated by the same company). E.g. travelling from Atlanta to New Delhi may consist of two legs, Atlanta - New York, and New York - New Delhi.
2. each leg has its own reservation that can be in the state "pending" or "confirmed" (this is really just a shortcut of the real states).
3. Each of the leg reservations are only allowed to transition from "pending" to "confirmed" once the booking partner (e.g. airline) has confirmed the reservation. These are asynchronous events that may take from seconds to days.
4. All leg reservations are bundled in a parent reservation that represents the state of the customer booking reservation. The parent reservation is only allowed to transition from "pending" to "confirmed" once a) all the associated legs are "confirmed", and b) once the payment from the customer has been made. Note in reality there is a distinction between "booking confirmed" and "payment confirmed", but I am simplifying here for brevity.
5. All communication happens through asynchronous service interfaces, i.e. it can take from seconds to days until the confirmation for leg bookings or the payment are received.

Note that the itinerary booking subsystem is separate from the payment subsystem, i.e. the reservation system can only determine the parent reservation state by querying both subsystems. Both subsystems receive asynchronous events and also implement callbacks to the reservation system when some event occurs.

Also note that the system is supposed to be used for different customers, whereby each can have its own set of states/transitions (for parent reservations).

Questions:

- What are common approaches to manage the state of a central, i.e. a parent reservation, that relies on the state of external subsystems?
- In particular, given the asynchronous nature of the confirmations from subsystems, how to keep track of the various sub states?
- Are there components out of the box to implement such a distributed FSM (in the Python ecosystem)?

I have been pondering the following approaches:

1. Implement a "parent reservation [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)" that repeatedly tries to switch the state from "pending" to "confirmation", each time querying the respective payment and leg reservation states. In this scenario, the FSM is pro-actively trying to get to the next state (or timeout at some point). This would be implemented as a periodic Celery task that quite simply queries the subsystems e.g. every 30-60 seconds.
2. Implement an abstract FSM (i.e. workflow) that receives callbacks from each subsystem once its state changes. In this scenario the FSM keeps track of all the callbacks/events it received, and once it received a "payment ok" and "leg ok" for all legs event, it would switch the state to "confirmation". In this case the FSM is passively waiting for events to arrive. This would be implemented as a parent reservation object that keeps track of the callbacks it received, then sets the state of the parent reservation.

The first approach does not appear scalable, while the second approach has the disadvantage of having to keep track of states individually. What I am really looking for is a component that would solve this without having to explicitly <s>model</s> code it, allow to set an arbitrary configuration for the parent reservation FSM.

Implementation is in Python, using Celery/RabbitMQ and Django.

Comment: I don't understand something you say about your second proposed solution. You say it is disadvantaged by having to keep track of each component's state. But if each component can transition from pending to confirmed, aren't you keeping track of them anyway?

Comment: @Garry Cairns, yes, each component keeps track of them. What I mean is that the reservation system would duplicate the state tracking of each component.  So the reservation system basically re-implements the FSMs of the subsystems which is what I meant by disadvantage.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested refinement of your second option:

1. Create an intermediary object/database table called something like `PendingBookings`. Among its data is a foreign key to the main booking and a count of pending legs. I'm assuming here that the number of pending legs will be non-zero at the initial booking.
2. Whenever a leg is created its save method also increments the corresponding pending leg count in the `PendingBookings` object.
3. Whenever a leg is confirmed its save method also decrements the pending leg count.
4. When the pending leg count reaches 0 its save method launches a transaction that updates the main booking to confirmed status and deletes the `PendingBookings` instance.

This means you don't have to poll things repeatedly, and also gives you a single location to find information about any bookings that have started but not finished. You could then poll that much less frequently, perhaps once a day into an `OLAP` cube to get information about bookings proceeding through the system.

I would also argue that there's no duplication here - you're storing useful state information in one place and eliminating it when you no longer need it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Garry. I'm not sure I like the counting down as it is not idempotent. Given that the intermediary table would receive status updates as a message (i.e. webservice call or via asynchronous message delivery) the system would require exactly-once semantics and reliable message delivery which is relatively hard to achieve.